# Linear Algebra Simple Basis Question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> Let $W = \operatorname{span}(x^2, x, x^2 + x, 1 + x + x^2)$ Find the basis of $W$.

Here's my solution. $\{0,0,1\}, \{0, 1, 0\}, \{0, 1, 1\}, \{1, 1, 1\}$. I just want to make sure that it's correct.

Comment: The elements of $W$ are polynomials. The things that you provided are sets of real numbers. What is the connection?

Comment: No.  It's not correct.  What you found are the "coordinates" of each polynomial with respect to the ordered basis $(1,x,x^2)$ (though you really should have put round brackets for those, not curly brackets).  You're going to need to go back to your textbook and look up what a "basis" is.

Comment: Be careful with using curly brackets $\{1,0,1\}$. They are usually used for a sets, which are unordered, i.e. $\{1,2,3\} = \{1,3,2\} = \{2,1,3\} = \{2,3,1\} = \{3,1,2\} = \{3,2,1\}$. We tend to use round brackets when the order matters: $(1,2,3) \neq (1,3,2) \neq (2,1,3) \neq (2,3,1) \neq (3,1,2) \neq (3,2,1)$.

Comment: It is not correct to speak of "the" basis; rather you should speak of "a" basis. There are many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many vectors. Your vector space is three dimensional so can only have three vectors in its basis.

You're right to associate $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ with $(a_0,a_1,a_2)$.

So $x^2 \sim (0,0,1)$, $x \sim (0,1,0)$, $x^2+x \sim (0,1,1)$ and $1+x+x^2 \sim (1,1,1)$.

To find a basis for the span of $(0,0,1)$, $(0,1,0)$, $(0,1,1)$ and $(1,1,1)$ we put them into a matrix and perform row operations.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right] \stackrel{R_3-R_2}{\longrightarrow}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right] \stackrel{R_3+R_4}{\longrightarrow}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right] $$

That means that row three was a linear combination of the other rows. We can check that the remaining rows -- $(1,1,1)$, $(0,1,1)$ and $(0,0,1)$ -- are linearly independent:
$$\det\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]=1 \neq 0$$
So $1+x+x^2$, $x+x^2$ and $x^2$ form a basis for $W$.

A bit more work with row operations will give $1,x,x^2$ are a basis.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\{0,0,1\}$ is identified with $x^2$ and for the others similarly, we have 
$\{0,0,1\} + \{0,1,0\} = \{0,1,1\}$.
So these vectors can't form a basis, since they are not linearly independent.